# How update related fields in django models

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-models

I am trying to update Parent model a related record, but getting an error.

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: update or delete on table "t_parent" violates foreign key constraint "t_child_marz_name_am_620d4c8d_fk_t_parent_marz_name_am" on table "t_child"
DETAIL:  Key (marz_name_am)=(Avan) is still referenced from table "t_child".
```

There is my models:

```
class Child(models.Model):
    child_pk            =   models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=60, blank=True, null=False)
    marz_name_am        =   models.ForeignKey('Parent', on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='marz_name_am', db_column='marz_name_am', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed                     = True
        db_table                    = 't_child'
        verbose_name_plural         = 'Child'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.child_pk  


class Parent(models.Model):
    marz_name           =   models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=60, blank=True, null=False)
    marz_name_am        =   models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=False, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        managed                     = True
        db_table                    = 't_parent'
        verbose_name_plural         = 'Parent'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.marz_name
```

When I delete a record everything works well.
I tried to reassign the **save()** method, but I got an error about infinite recursion (maybe I did something wrong ...);
I read that I can reassign the **pre_save()**, **post_save()** method - but as I understand it, they are used mainly for checks before saving and in general I do not know how to do this.
P.S. This is just an example of the models for which I am testing the problem!

Comment: Can you try accessing the entries directly through the command line, as referenced in [this article](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-delete/)? Or are you really looking for a way to do this in Django

Comment: @crimsonpython24 
I am looking for a way to do this through Django. However, I tried to modify the entry through the DBeaver Database Visualizer - but was getting an error.
 ``` 
SQL Error [23503]: ERROR: update or delete on table "t_parent" violates foreign key constraint "t_child_marz_name_am_620d4c8d_fk_t_parent_marz_name_am" on table "t_child".
```
Tables were created through django migrations.